# VBA Subscript out of range, name resolution problem?

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to write a VBA function that will return the column number given the header cell string and the worksheet name but I get the Subscript out of range error. 
Here is the function:

```
Public Function namedColumnNo(heading As String, shtName As String) As Long
' Return the column number with named header text'
' on given worksheet.
Dim r As Range
Dim wks As Worksheet

Debug.Print shtName
'Exit Function

Set wks = Sheets(shtName)
wks.Range("1:1").Select
With wks
    r = .Range("1:1").Find(heading, LookIn:=xlValue)
    If r Is Nothing Then
        namedColumnNo = -1
    Else: namedColumnNo = r.Column
    End If

End With

End Function
```

I am using this test sub to call the funtion:

```
Public Sub getCol()

Debug.Print "Find MidTemp on " & DataSht.RawDataSht
Debug.Print "Col " & namedColumnNo("MidTemp", DataSht.RawDataSht)

End Sub
```

I have a user defined type DataSht where I have variables to name worksheets e.g.

```
Public Type dataShtNames
    HeaderSht As String
    RawDataSht As String
    ResultDataSht As String
End Type
Public DataSht As dataShtNames
```

With the Exit Function statement uncommented the variables resolve OK with the debug.print statements I get

```
Find MidTemp on RawData
RawData:MidTemp
Col 0
```

Leaving the function to run through the error occurs at
`Set wks = Sheets(shtName)`
If I replace the argument shtName with the actual sheet name as a string "RawData", then the error moves down to the line using the second argument `heading`. If I substitute a the parameter with a string here the error persists. 
Is there something I am missing here? Some help will be much appreciated.

Comment: When you call the function it assumes you are passing the variables for heading and shtname.  Because you are not, the values are nothing and you will get the error because no such sheet or heading exists.

Comment: `r = .Range("1:1").Find(heading, LookIn:=xlValue)` is missing a `Set` keyword. I'm surprised that isn't throwing error 91.

Comment: I'm curious about whether these sheets exist at compile-time in `ThisWorkbook`, and whether the "headings" actually belong to `ListObject` (table) objects. If that is the case, there's a much, much simpler way to go about this.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon yes, the sheet does exist as I am using this function after creating new worksheets and applying names from the `DataSht.` variables. However, I will take the advice and learn more about the `ListObject` as I'm all for simpler solutions. Thanks

Comment: Ctrl+T (in Excel) is your new best friend ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly can't comment, but you're actually getting the `out of range` error because it should be `LookIn:=xlValues` where you have `LookIn:=xlValue`

As @Mathieu indicates, you'll need to fix add `Set r = Find(heading, LookIn:=xlValues)` to set the range to the value returned.

As a side note-you should drop the selection.  Its not doing anything for you.

```
With wks.Range("1:1")
   Set r = .Find(heading, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If r Is Nothing Then
        namedColumnNo = -1
    Else: namedColumnNo = r.Column
    End If

End With
```

Comment: Wow, nice catch! Confirmed repro (throws error 91 once the typo is fixed, without the `Set` added). This would have been prevented with `Option Explicit` being specified at the top of the module.

Comment: I would also suspect a possible error #9 at `Sheets(shtName)`, if that code isn't written in the `ThisWorkbook` module and the `ActiveWorkbook` (to which an unqualified `Sheets` call is then an implicit/indirect reference to) doesn't have a worksheet by that name. I would also advocate to use the `Worksheets` collection instead, to rule out the possibility of a type mismatch when the given name pulls, say, some `Chart` sheet - however unlikely that is.

Comment: Also, congrats! You now have enough rep to comment everywhere! =)

Comment: The missing `Set` and `xlValues` has cured the problem, big tick and thanks. Also appreciate the refined code. I had actually put the `.Select` statement in as a visible 'debug' flag, so yes, redundant. @Mathieu your helpful advice duly noted, VBA objects and variables scope is driving me nuts!!